# c# rendercontrol to an html file

Tags: c#, webforms, user-controls, asp.net-2.0

I am trying to rendercontrol an asp.net panel into an html file.  The following is the code section related to this.

```
public void CreateHTMLFile(string outHTMLFile)
{
    System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    _reportPanel.RenderControl(hw);
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

```
protected void downloadPDFLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        datesLiteral.Text = startDate.Text + " to " + endDate.Text;
        schoolID = Convert.ToInt32(schoolDropDownList.SelectedValue);
        BuildIntro();
        BuildCoachingReportTableMain();
        BuildMinutesTable();
        BuildContentAreasTable();
        BuildFrameworkTable();
        BuildTeacherMinutes();
        reportPanel.Visible = true;
        selectionPanel.Visible = false;
        selectionLinkButton.Visible = false;
        PDFLinkButton.Visible = false;
        string reportTitle = "<h1>" + "" + "</h1>";
        PDFConversion pc = new PDFConversion();
        pc.Convert(PDFPanel, reportTitle, false, "open");
        selectionLinkButton.Visible = true;
        PDFLinkButton.Visible = true;

    }

public void Convert(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel reportPanel, string reportTitle,
                    bool fontSmall, string action)
{
    PanelToHTMLForPDF panelHP = new PanelToHTMLForPDF(reportPanel, reportTitle, fontSmall);
    _isNetPanelToPDF = true;
    Convert(panelHP, action);
}

public PanelToHTMLForPDF(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel reportPanel, string     reportTitle,
                    bool fontSmall)
{
    _reportPanel = reportPanel;
    _reportTitle = reportTitle;
    _fontSmall = fontSmall;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I tested and the it looks like its not the asp.net literals that are causing the error.

Comment: How is `_reportPanel` initialized? If it is `null` that explains the error trivially.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation here.. also show your code we can't see what you see on your end.. [C# MSDN Control.RenderControl Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/htwek607(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I have added an update for the sections related to how the _reportPanel is initialized.

Comment: You're sure that `PanelToHTMLForPDF` is called before `CreateHTMLFile` and that the statelessness of the web isn't causing an issue here? Note that you have `reportPanel` as a member of the page `_reportPanel` that is also used and `reportPanel` that is a parameter that may cause some confusion.

Comment: Yes, PanelToHTMLForPDF is called before CreateHTMLFile because CreateHTMLFile is called within the function Convert(panelHP, action) within the Convert function shown above.  Yes, I could see how the reportPanel naming could be confusing.  This was the naming convention that was supplied and has been able to create HTML files in the past.

Comment: What do you mean by the statelessness of the web?  Are you referring to the overall sense that values are not preserved on the web?  Does this relate to the asp.net literals I was referring to?